# How Pycharm is related to Anaconda and Python?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am getting an error while installing the package

```
pyramid-arima
```

I tried the following but could not resolve the issue

```
conda create -n pmdissue23 --yes --quiet python=3.5 numpy scipy 
scikit-learn statsmodels

activate pmdissue23

pip install pyramid-arima
```

Output of above commands:

```
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.9 in 
/anaconda/envs/pmdissue23/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pyramid- 
arima)
Installing collected packages: Cython, pyramid-arima

changing mode of //anaconda/envs/pmdissue23/bin/cython to 755
changing mode of //anaconda/envs/pmdissue23/bin/cygdb to 755
changing mode of //anaconda/envs/pmdissue23/bin/cythonize to 755

Successfully installed Cython-0.28.1 pyramid-arima-0.6.2
Cleaning up...
```

But again the package is not installed correctly and pycharm asks me to download the package. This leads me to the following questions.

I am using Pycharm on windows 10 and having issues how pycharm is configured to use python. I installed python and Anaconda on my system prior to installation of Pycharm. I selected the interpreter as Anaconda when I created the first program.

Below are my questions:

Why is pycharm creating a new virtual environment for python interpreter instead of using the original installation. ( This causes me to import all the packages for each new project I create)

Should I use Anaconda or Python interpreter. I am not sure which one is the right one. Or should I have both.

I am having problems installing packages (pycharm gives me an error that my pip is not updated). However from my command line I updated the pip to the latest version. How do I connect pycharm to the latest pip.

Last question, How can I import all the data science packages to my python installation and point pycharm to read those packages instead of writing explicit import statements.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

I reinstalled python on my machine. Updated the pip and other packages.

Comment: When you setup an environment you can choose to make it available to other projects. If you do not tick in the box, you will not be able to use it for another project.

If you choose to use anaconda and conda environments then I suggest you use `conda` to install your package. I also suggest that you use the Pycharm embedded terminal to do so if you are new to these tools. (This will prevent most of the rookie mistakes of installing packages in the wrong environment.)

Comment: Also, you can do `conda env list` to get a list of the conda environments you have.
Finally, updating pip can be done using `python -m pip install -U pip`